# Which style sheet selector for widgets in a layout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtstylesheets

Asuming we have a `QFormLayout` with `objectName` set to `"formLayout"`.
This layout consists of two `QLabel` and `QLineEdit` and objects:

```
formLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")

label1 = QtGui.QLabel()    
label2 = QtGui.QLabel()

lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
lineEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()

formLayout.addRow(label1, lineEdit1)
formLayout.addRow(label2, lineEdit2)
```

Now i want to change the style of the `QLabel`'s/`QLineEdit`'s in the `formLayout` with an external `.qss` file. I would expect something like this:

```
QFormLayout#formLayout > QLabel, QLineEdit{
    /*set some styles for QLabel/QLineEdit in the formLayout*/
}
```

Unfortunatly this isn't working. I know i could set all `QLabel`'s in `formLayout` to the same object name:

```
label1 = QtGui.setObjectName("formLayoutLabel")    
label2 = QtGui.setObjectName("formLayoutLabel")
```

and set their style like this:

```
QLabel#formLayoutLabel{
    /*set some styles for QLabel in the formLayout*/
}
```

**My Question:**

How can I change the style of all widgets of a specific type (in example `QLabel` and `QLineEdit`) located in a parent layout/widget (in example `formLayout`) within a external `.qss` without using object name property?

Comment: All layouts *must* have a parent, and all widgets inside that layout will be automatically reparented to its parent. So just give the parent of the layout an object-name, then in your global stylesheet you can do `#formParent QLabel { ... }`, etc. See: [Stylesheet Selector Types](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) for other options.

Comment: In my case the hirarchy looks like this:
`QDialog -> QVBoxLayout-> QHBoxLayout -> QFormLayout`. So the parent of all layouts is `QDialog` right? In order to only modify components of the formlayout i have to add a container widget for it which will result in this: `QDialog -> QVBoxLayout-> QHBoxLayout -> QWidget -> QFormLayout`. I have tested this and it works. Is this the best solution or can i do better with out a "helper container widget".

Comment: Another question: Is this approach best practice? Or should they just have the same object name as mentioned in the example above. Basically: Modify style of QWidgets by same parent vs. same object name?

Comment: I don't think there is any one "best" solution. You just need to pick whichever one is most appropriate in the context of the application you are currently developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QLayout` derived classes are not `QWidget` derived, which leave them out of the Qt style system altogether.

A way to solve the issue is to back each layout with a widget, i.e. don't let a widget have more than one layout. This way all the widgets (i.e. labels) belonging to the layout are also children of the same widget, in which you can inject the stylesheet:

```
QLabel {
    /*set some styles for QLabel in the formLayout*/
}
```

So, if you have a widget with, say, four layouts, you should put four children widgets in it and put each layout inside one of them (then lay out the widgets the same way you previously arranged the layouts).

An alternative workaround consists of subclassing the widgets and, in the stylesheet, select them by type name. For example, if you have *special* labels in a layout, use the simplest possible `QLabel` subclass:

```
class Layout1Label(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Layout1Label, self).__init__(parent)
```

then add only labels of that type to the layout:

```
label = Layout1Label()
layout.addWidget(label)
```

and refer to them in the stylesheet:

```
Layout1Label {
    /*set some styles for all labels in layout*/
}
```

This should be effective, but can get tedious and require much effort (also you could end up with a lot of types, only meant for the stylesheet selection sake).

Comment: It is impossible for a widget to have more than one layout. And by the same token, all layouts must have a parent (otherwise their contained widgets won't be layout out). Any widget inside a layout will be automatically reparented to whatever widget the layout is set on. Thus all the widgets in a layout (and its sublayouts) will form a natural hierarchy. If this wasn't true. nested layouts couldn't possibly work, and the same goes for cascading stylesheets. It also follows from this that it is impossible for a widget to belong to more than one layout.

Comment: Sorry, it must be a matter of words. I mean a widget can **contain** more than one layout, other than the widget's own one. Using children/parent relationship terminology about layouts can also be misleading, because they're not Qwidget subclasses.

Comment: It is not misleading at all. All layout classes inherit QObject, and so do all widget subclasses. So they most emphatically *do* form child/parent relationships. As I said above, layouts and qss couldn't possibly work if that wasn't true. The object hierarchy is absolutely essential: that's why all widgets inside layouts are automatically reparented.

Comment: It's misleading in the context of style: yes there are parent objects and children objects, but some of them participate in **style hierarchies** (widgets) others just don't (layouts).